# Wrong DML process, update old values

Tags: dml

I have updated one object records with wrong SOQL, how can I set all values as previous?

Comment: Did you have history tracking on the field? If not, is there a way to determine the old values?

Comment: Yes, there is history tracking

Comment: post your query and what value(s) has been chaged.

Comment: If there's history tracking you can simply use the history tracking table to restore the old values. Just use `SELECT OldValue, NewValue, FieldName FROM MyObject__History WHERE CreatedDate = :aroundTheTimeYouDidTheUpdate AND FieldName = 'MyField__c'`

Comment: I need to do this dynamiclly because there are many records

Comment: @cloudZigZag 2 field has been changed currencyisocode and amount. This object is a custom object

Comment: @rael_kid with this query how can I use oldValue as currency? I couldn't assign

Comment: You have to query for updates on both the CurrencyIsoCode and Amount__c fields (although I'm not 100% sure CurrencyIsoCode can be history tracked). Then you can assign the OldValue of the corresponding History record to the Amount__c and CurrencyIsoCode field.